# Getting duplicate records while storing into the data base oracle 11g

Tags: java, database, oracle11g

My program will read the data from the CSV file and insert each and every record into the data base. But the problem is, if there are 200 records, while retrieving it, it  is showing 212 records containing some of the duplicate records. How to solve this?

Comment: can you add some code , some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a primary key to you table to ensure no duplicate records can be inserted.
Else you can also go for Merge statement to avoid duplicates.

Example for Merge:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement.php

Comment: Even though I add the primary key,same problem occurs.Its stating that unique constraint violated,I checked whether it is really violating the constraint or not.But there are no repetitive values in that CSV file.But it is showing error as it contains the duplicate values.

Comment: In this case you can do 2 things, catch the exception to find out which records are causing problem [may be using reading them twice]. If nothing helps go for Merge statement, all will go well even if you have duplicate records.

Comment: How to do that merging

Comment: I have added example for merge statement in answer.

Comment: My problem is particular row position is getting repeated all the time.Whatever the values that are present in the particular row position,those are getting added two times into database.

Comment: What do you mean by row position?